# UIDocumentPickerViewController in import mode returns .icloud files

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

using a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in `.import` mode on iCloud Drive sometimes returns files with a `.icloud` extension. This extension means that the file are not physically present on the device, but on iCloud.

Since the mode is `.import`, the files returned by 
`documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])`
are a copy of the actual files.
Therefore, it becomes impossible to call `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL` on `NSFileManager`.

One precision that might (maybe) be important: this happens when the user selects a directory in the `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL`. In the callback I then perform `FileManager.default.enumerator(at: urls[0], includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)` which returns the list of files inside the directory. Some of those files unfortunately are sometimes .icloud files, not the actual files.

Somehow, I can't find a workaround to access those files, any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, this is a bug on their side. .icloud files should not be returned.